# ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at line 1 when trying to run a stored proc using ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm working on building an interface that will run stored procedures from an Oracle database through my .NET Winforms application.  I'm able to successfully connect to the Oracle Database and can succussfully use the ODP.NET API to retrieve a list of all the stored procedures and all the parameters for any of the stored procedures I pick.

The problem exists when I try to run the stored procedure.  It breaks when I attempt to execute and returns Oracle errors telling me there are no records, but when I run the stored procedure from sql developer, it returns exactly what I'm looking for.  Here is the stored procedure:

```
    create or replace procedure sp_get_emp_info 
    (
       empid in INTEGER,
       m_UserName  out VARCHAR2,
       m_Email out VARCHAR2,
       m_IsActive out INTEGER
    ) as 
    begin
     SELECT 
       UserName,
       Email,
       IsActive
     INTO
       m_UserName,
       m_Email,
       m_IsActive
     FROM
       MICHAELTABLE
     WHERE ID = empid;
    end sp_get_emp_info;
```

Here is a test class I wrote just to attempt reading this in C#:

```
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
    using System;

    namespace OracleTester
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                      
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=apps;Password=apps;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Orchid64)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = MVP)));";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;

            //string procs = "SELECT object_name FROM dba_objects WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE' AND owner = 'APPS'";
            //OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(procs, conn);
            //cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            //cmd.Connection.Open();
            //OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            //int i = 1;
            //while (reader.Read())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(i + ". " +reader.GetString(0));
            //    i++;
            //}

            OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "SP_GET_EMP_INFO";
            comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Connection = conn;

            OracleParameter user = new OracleParameter("m_UserName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 25);
            user.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            OracleParameter email = new OracleParameter("m_Email", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
            email.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            OracleParameter active = new OracleParameter("m_IsActive", OracleDbType.Double, 38);
            active.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            comm.Parameters.Add(user);
            comm.Parameters.Add(email);
            comm.Parameters.Add(active);

            OracleParameter empID = new OracleParameter("empid", OracleDbType.Double, 38);
            empID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            empID.SourceColumn = "empid";
            empID.Value = 1;
            comm.Parameters.Add(empID);



            comm.Connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["m_UserName"].ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Server Version: " + conn.ServerVersion);
            conn.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run this, here is the exception I receive this:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled
  DataSource=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsRecoverable=false
  Message=ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "APPS.SP_GET_EMP_INFO", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
  Number=1403
  Procedure=""
  Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
  StackTrace:
       at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
       at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
       at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at OracleTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\TestProjects\OracleTester\OracleTester\Program.cs:line 54
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you've just set the data up in SQL Developer, have you committed the changes? Maybe you're just querying it in the same session that created it - so it's expected that another session (from .Net in this case) can't see it yet.

Comment: Nope, it's been a stored proc for months.

Comment: Are you logging in as the same user in code as in SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes, same user in both environments.

Comment: I'm not asking about the procedure, I'm asking about the data - was the row in MICHAELTABLE with ID=1 recently inserted, and if so has that been committed?

Comment: Yes, it has also been there for months as well.  :)

Comment: OK, always worth checking. My only other thought is to wonder if it's entirely happy with named parameters; I've seen a problem before where even when naming the position was actually used, but can't recall which platform or driver that was. Just to check, can you reorder the `Add` calls to match the order in the procedure specification?

Comment: Okay, that fixed the exception, which is awesome, but it didn't return my column value I asked for in the reader while loop.  any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be looking at `user.value` after executing the procedure, to see the OUT parameter value; rather than the result set which I imagine is empty in this case?

Comment: That worked!  I changed my ExecuteReader call to ExecuteNonQuery and then checked values on ouput parameters and the results were there.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971518.aspx#odpvsmsdp_topic4):

> By default, ODP.NET parameters for **OracleCommand.CommandType = Text** commands are bound by position. The **OracleCommand** class provides a **BindByName** property—set this property to true to bind parameters by name instead of by position.

You're creating named parameters but they're actually being added positionally, which means you're effectively supplying a value for the `m_IsActive` (despite it being an OUT parameter) and leaving `empid` null, as far as the procedure is concerned.

You could set `comm.BindByName=true` as @b_levitt pointed out in comments. Alternatively if you reorder the parameter assignment to match the formal argument order it will pick up the right value:

```
OracleParameter empID = new OracleParameter("empid", OracleDbType.Double, 38);
empID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
empID.SourceColumn = "empid";
empID.Value = 1;
comm.Parameters.Add(empID);

comm.Parameters.Add(user);
comm.Parameters.Add(email);
comm.Parameters.Add(active);

comm.Connection.Open();
OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't seem very clear on what the return value will contain when the CommandType property is set to StoredProcedure, and it may have something useful if you're calling a function; but with a procedure call there is no associated result set, so this will presumably be empty. Looping over it won't find anything:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rdr["m_UserName"].ToString());
}
```

Instead you can refer directly to the OUT parameter's value:

```
Console.WriteLine(user.value);
```

Comment: Regarding parameter order, he could set comm.BindByName=true;

Comment: @b_levitt - you should make that a separate answer *8-)

Comment: I considered that but, you're the one that identified the ordering issue, I only added provider specific fix.  I think you should add it to your answer.